# What should be the target variable shape? should it be (n,1) or (n,)?

Tags: pandas, logistic-regression

I tried logistic regression on the titanic dataset but used 2 different code:
1st code:

```
# did all the data preparation
d = pd.read_csv("titanic.csv")

x = d.values[:,1:]
y = d.values[:,1]
m.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

and fit the data in and got an accuracy of 97.3%.
but in 2nd code i used

```
x = d.values[:,1:]
y = d.values[:,:1]
m.fit(x_train, y_train.ravel())
```

and fit the data in the model and got an accuracy of 75.7%.

The only difference is, in the first code y shape was (183,) and in the second code, y shape was (183,1). so which one is correct? what should be the shape of the target variable?
find full the [first code](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/Bl4DtZF3EN) and [second code](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/tUk3GuJGFL) here.

Comment: show a few values of your y data for both cases please

Comment: Should be closed as typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are retrivng a different column as $y$ on each option.

**In option 1**:

```
y = d.values[:, :1]
```

You are correctly retriving the $Survived$ column

**In option 2**:

```
y = d.iloc[:,1]
```

What retrieves the column $Pclass$

So in short: To get the same results just change in the option 2
`y = d.iloc[:,1]` to

```
y = d.iloc[:,0]
```